# How to fix an error at start after compiling with PyInstaller got pyodbc?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, pyinstaller

I have writen a program in  python (`pyodbc` and `tkinter`). I used `pyodbc` to connect to Microsoft Access Database.

There is the connection Code:

```
import pyodbc

# Microsoft Access Database File
DBfile = 'GDP.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
```

When I start it before compiling in command prompt (`python myprogram.py`) it works very well. When compiling with `pyinstaller` all goes well, no errors are reported.

But When trying to launch the executabl it shows the main window for 2 seconds which then disappears.

When I used the `-d` flag in `pyinstaller` to turn on debug mode it shows the following error when launching the executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 62, in <module>
  pyodbc.Error: (
     'HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]
     Can't find File'(Unknown)'. 
     (-1811) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]
     Can't find File'(Unknown)'.
     (-1811)")
RC: -1 from main
```

**EDIT** 
first error gone , got a new one :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 78, in 
File "path\to\my\program\ build\pyi.win32\GDP\outPYZ1.pyz/Tkinter", line 1564, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico' not defined
RC: -1 from main
```

Comment: Edit: "urgent" is not welcome in the question title. We all have busy lives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use an absolute filename, not a local file:

```
import os

try:
    currdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except NameError:  # We are the main py2exe script, not a module
    import sys
    currdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
DBfile = os.path.join(currdir, 'GDP.mdb')
```

Comment: The solution from @Martijn Pieters above diagnosed my problem (I needed to change filename of my Access db to the absolute filename), but I had to tweak his solution for my situation. When I joined the current dir per his instructions and then printed the path to the terminal, I saw that it included the name of my .py file in the path, which wasn't correct, probably because I was importing the function that opened and read the db into that file. When I hardcoded the correct absolute path, it worked perfectly. Thanks Martjin!

Comment: @jenstreetman: yes, there was a `os.path.dirname()` call missing, added now.